# Why "diagonal" polarization doesn't decohere?

Tags: quantum-information, polarization, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

It is often said, that qubit should be maintained under very low temperature and kept highly isolated not to decohere.

But we can represent $|0\rangle$ with vertical polarization of light and $|1\rangle$ with horizontal polarization of light. The the superposition $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$ will be represented with 45 degree polarization.

And diagonal polarized light will calmly propagate over space without decohering, i.e. without collapsing to $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

Why?

Comment: *"It is often said, that qubit should be maintained under very low temperature and kept highly isolated not to decohere."* -- Who is saying this about qubits encoded in photons?

Comment: So, this is because this qubit is of photons? Why do qubits of photones don't decohere?